# Auto-fill a repeating pattern in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to use auto-fill to continue a pattern, however it's skipping several numbers as it fills.

For example, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

> Column A
>
> =Sheet1!A1
>
> =Sheet1!B1
>
> =Sheet1!C1

Using auto-fill, however, skips 3 each time, so it ends up like this:

> =Sheet1!A4
>
> =Sheet1!B4
>
> =Sheet1!C4
>
> =Sheet1!A7
>
> =Sheet1!B7
>
> =Sheet1!C7

What I'd like the next part of the pattern to fill to is (thanks @ScottCraner for clarifying):

> =Sheet1!A2
>
> =Sheet1!B2
>
> =Sheet1!C2

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, or an alternate method of filling the pattern? Thanks!

Comment: So the next in your desired sequesnce is `=Sheet1!D1` or is it `=Sheet1!A2`?

Comment: @ScottCraner The latter. Thank you for pointing out the clarification, I edited that into the question.

Answer (score 3):

This formula will give the desired pattern as you fill down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:C,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)+1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,3)+1)
```

If you are filling accross replace both `ROW(1:1)` with `COLUMN(A:A)`

To show it works I filled Sheet 1 columns A:C with their addresses:

[image]